# How to send JSON date fields to web core API?

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this AJAX request;

```
   addDataToDatabase = function (callback, errorCallback, url, data) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "text",
            data: data,
            type: "POST"
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                callback(data);
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                errorCallback(data);
            });
```

which sends data to the web core API;

> data  "{\"InspectionId\":\"4471\",\"DateOfVisit\":\"25/09/2017
>   00:00:00\",\"NoAccessId\":\"2\",\"NoAccessComment\":\"lkjh
>   lkjhlkjhlkhjlkjhlklkjh lkh lkh kjh dsf\"}"

Which is pick up with this method

```
[HttpPost("addNoAccess")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddNoAccessVisit([FromBody] InspectionVisitNoAccessDto noAccessVisit)
```

The definition of the dto is

```
public class InspectionVisitNoAccessDto
    {
        public int InspectionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfVisit { get; set; }
        public int NoAccessId { get; set; }
        public string NoAccessComment { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"No Access Inspection Visit, date of visit {DateOfVisit.ToLongDateString()}, id = {NoAccessId}, comment = {NoAccessComment}";
        }
    }
```

The DateOfVisit field is a date field. With the this definition, the input string for the date field does not appear to be converted from a string to a date field, as the whole object is null.
But if I change the definition from DateTime to string, everything is fine.
But I would prefer to keep the definition as it is. Is there something with the JSON input I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

instead of sending the date in format `25/09/2017 00:00:00`, try to send it in **ISO8601** format.

Example:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();

// result
2017-09-29T14:15:39.409Z
```

Example is taken from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp)